# Permanent (301) .htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, permanent

I need a 301 redirect from these pages:

```
form/5/asd.html
form/5/12dasd.html
form/5/dasidjasd.html
form/5/pasd1.html
```

Always to this page: `/form/12/name.html`

Can you help me, because I never understand .htaccess redirects :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use RedirectMatch with a wildcard, and remember to use the complete URL when specifying where to redirect to:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /form/5/.* www.example.com/form/12/name.html
```

Comment: Better to use: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/form/5/ /form/12/name.html` No need of full URL in target.