# Category .htaccess redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess

Main Category: I wanna redirect this /listing.php?cat=1 to this with htaccess /listing/cat/1/Cars-&-Bikes/ . Sql: /listing/cat/cat_id/cat_name/

Sub Category: I wanna redirect this /listing.php?subcat=1 to this with htaccess /listing/subcat/4/Bikes-&-Scooters/ . Sql: /listing/subcat/subcat_id/sub_cat_name/

How can i redirect these

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us your code? Please explain what the `Sql` URLs are supposed to do and why you included them. Are they relevant for your answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permanent (301) .htaccess redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25081070/permanent-301-htaccess-redirect)

Comment: I solved thank you